# Javascript css transition for vertical size does not work

Tags: javascript, css

I Have an element named 'frame'. 
I have a button with code linked with 'onlclik'.
The idea is apply a height decrease transition to this 'frame'.

This code results into a simple frame hide, without transition.

```
frame.style.cssText+="transition: height 1500ms; -webkit-transition: height 1500ms;";
frame.style.height = "0px";
//frame.style.display = "block";
```

(The last line can be applied or not, getting the same result.)

I can play with increasing or decreasing the height, but in both cases the height is applied instantly. There is not transition...

Now the surprising behavioor.... The transition works fine !!!
I write any height at the styles chrome debugger window and I see the transition works !!

What is the reason becasue the transition does not work at code level ?

I have another similar transition code for width increase and it works fine.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your height within a `setTimeout` callback:

```
frame.style.cssText+="transition: height 1500ms; -webkit-transition: height 1500ms;";
setTimeout(function() { frame.style.height = "0px"; }, 0);
```

`setTimeout` with a `0` delay essentially instructs the browser to wait until the current UI thread completes before executing the supplied callback. For more on why `setTimeout` with a `0` delay is useful, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful).

Comment: I imagined something like this. TH.